# It's possible to run multiple java packages each package has a main class

Tags: java, eclipse, java-package

I have many packages that have classes  in an eclipse project under src package  each package has a main class  each   class like this

```
public class A extends TimerTask {
public A()
{
}
@Override
public void run() {

    new A();    } }
```

and each other class like this

```
public class MainClass 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {   
 java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
timer.schedule( new A(), 0, 1000);;
timer.schedule( new B(),0,1000);
}
  }
```

But I fail to execute two packages as the same time.
Could someone suggest?

Comment: There can only be one *program entry point* (per launched Java process) - but you are free to call the other classes' main method manually after that ..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run multiple main classes at same time. Define a flow. Such that one main class end up with starting another main.

```
main() {
...
...
...
callMainFromAnotherPackage();
}
```

Comment: This code could call Main From another package but don't to execute it

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar another.jar");
```

But don't forget to properly end process, else your machine can reach the limit for file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

You can start them in two different threads.